# Creating unique ID numbers for duplicate Excel rows

Tags: excel, xls, xlsx

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple columns. I'd like to automatically add unique ID numbers (starting in cell A2) to duplicate values in column D (starting at D2). Any way to make the spreadsheet look like below? Thanks.

```
Column A     Column D
1               3
1               3
2             Bard
2             Bard
3             4ton
3             4ton
3             4ton
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **A1** enter **1**

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(D1=D2,A1,A1+1)
```

and copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear on whether your data table has column header labels or not but this formula should not make a difference beyond having to pre-populate A1 if there is no column header label.

In A2 use this formula,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A1, MATCH(D2, D$1:D1, 0)), MAX(A$1:A1)+1)
```

Fill down as necessary. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Serial number matching]

While your column D was sorted, that is not a requirement with this formula.